# C# TCP protocol. Convert IP to URL

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ip

How I can convert ip to url? I want to create sniffer where user can see at the end of day list of sites and total time that he spend on the each site

```
static void Sniff(IPAddress ip)
{
    Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    //sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
    sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 0));
    sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
    sck.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[24];
    Action<IAsyncResult> OnReceive = null;
    OnReceive = (ar) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}\t{1}:{2}\t===>\t{3}:{4}"
            , buffer.Skip(9).First().ToProtocolString()
            , new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 12)).ToString()
            , ((ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 20))).ToString()
            , new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 16)).ToString()
            , ((ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 22))).ToString());
        buffer = new byte[24];
        sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 24, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    };

    sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
}

public static string ToProtocolString(this byte b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
        case 1: return "ICMP";
        case 6: return "TCP";
        case 17: return "UDP";
        default: return "#" + b.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: a single IP can host thousands of websites - its not that simple. You would do better to put in a proxy, and just report off what hes viewed

Comment: Can please more explain what I need do or how I can get url?

Comment: You cant from an IP. many IPs can be the same website, and 1 IP can be many websites (common in hosting environments).. it could be stackoverlow or it could be porn you have no way to know which website they went to via an IP (Im not suggesting stackoverflow shares with porn but its that simple)

Comment: so, what dll or code I need use for get url and time?

Comment: Just install a proxy server, block all http/https etc traffic unless it goes through the proxy - now you can monitor whos viewed what and when

Comment: Do you have some samples for C#?

Answer (score 0):

As BugFinder mentioned below your question: It is not as simple as finding the IP address to know what website a user is visiting. A single IP address can host multiple websites and there is no telling what website it is the one the user of the computer is visiting (unless you use a proxy, monitor the web requests or something like that).

In case knowing the host name is enough: You could use the [DNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx) object in C#. For example:

`static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ip = "8.8.8.8";
            Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName); //prints the host name
            Console.ReadKey();
        }`

Will give the following output in the console:

> google-public-dns-a.google.com

Comment: Do you have a sample of sniffer that return URLs?

Comment: Not URLs, Its **not** possible to go from IP to URL without a proxy over the network or being on the computer that is making the request and reading the URL out of the network packages.

Comment: this is not a good news for me. Can we on C# get all visited sited by day and total time for these sites?

Comment: these? what do you mean by 'these sites'? Do you have a selected set you are looking for?

Comment: It sounds like your a network administrator then. I think you are better of looking at a network wide solution (aka proxy) instead of a program on a computer. If I where a user at your computer I would simply kill every process that I don't know the function of. Alternativly you could see if you can utilize wire shark. It has a api's to several programming languages and wireshark is able to read the web requests. But I have no personal experience with it so I wouldn't know the details.

Comment: In most companies it would be frowned upon to use wireshark to monitor employees as you could read personal information. In fact at one point they legally had to warn people if you were going to be doing that kind of packet monitoring - however these days, this is usually simply done by use of a proxy and just reporting sites.. after all facebook has games, lots of sites have games..

Comment: @BugFinder that is true, I left all moral and social factors out of it thus far and just looked over the technical issues. Its up to MarianMelnychuk and those at the company in question to figure out how far they want to go. But yes I guess it would have been better if I pointed out that Wireshark is somewhat of a breach in the privacy of a user.

Comment: A proxy server is the simplest and most accepted method - plus, if it caches stuff reduces load on your outbound internet link.. blah blah blah

Comment: Do you have some samples to C#?

Comment: While you could write one - buy it.